# GADInterstitialAd not presenting in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

**Question:**(iOS)
i want to display `GADInterstitialAd` at `ApplicationDidBecomeActive` in AppDelegate. bellow is the code i'm using

```
- (void)showInterstitial{
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request]; // here you need to crate object of GADRequest
    request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
    GADInterstitial* interstitialAd = [[GADInterstitial alloc]initWithAdUnitID:AdvertismentID];
    interstitialAd.delegate = self;
    [interstitialAd loadRequest:request];
}
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:pagerViewController];
}
- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:FALSE withAnimation:NO];
    NSLog(@"==%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

-(void)interstitialWillPresentScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad{
    // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE withAnimation:NO];
    NSLog(@"on screen");
}
```

and i'm calling `[self showInterstitial]` in `ApplicationDidBecomeActive` 
i've added `<GADInterstitialDelegate>` but delegate methods are not calling even i'm not getting errors. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i got the answer.
simply used strong reference of `GADInterstitialAd` in above code.